# TwitterBootstrap event.relatedTarget() not returning clicked button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a TwitterBootstrap Modal window with dynamically loaded information. I want to load this information depending on which button is clicked. To do this, I tried using the event.relatedTarget() function, just like recommended in documentation.

Unfortunately, this does not return the clicked button, so I can't access the required data-types.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-type="close_service" data-id="<?php echo $currentServices["id"]; ?>">Close Service</button>

$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  console.log("modal opening"); // This properly logs, so nothing wrong with opening

  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  console.log(button); // returns n.fn.init[0] with a bunch of info that has nothing to do with my button

  var type = button.data('type'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  console.log(type); // returns undefined

});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems your code is working fine http://www.bootply.com/Wk7DlcNEei. check console.

Comment: I'm very confused. Any idea why it wouldn't work on my localhost? I'll keep playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you using bootstrap 2? In this case you must use:
$("#myModal").on('show',...

Instead of:
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal',

See http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals for more info